# Enabling redirects in urllib.requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I want to use urllib.requests, but I want the requests to allow redirects.

```
def get_html(url):
        req = Request(url)
        html = urlopen(req).read()
        return html
```

I want code like this:

```
def get_html(url):
        req = Request(url, allow_redirects=True)
        html = urlopen(req).read()
        return html
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use requests?
You can get the url that redirects, then after getting the page, get the url attribute:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(Your_URL)
#this will give you the destination url:
print(r.url)
```

Comment: Perfect Answer..!